# Close a android app from a second app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I have a main app that has to run 24/7. It writes some data every 20 mins to a file. I want to make a second app that checks the same file if data is being written every 20 mins. If not the second app should be able to close the main app and start it again. Is this possible?

Comment: use service instead of that second app

Answer (score 0):

You could for example setup a Broadcast Receiver in your manifest. Via sendBroadcast you can then send any kind of IntentExtra (String, Integer, Boolean, whatever) from one app to another (commanding it to do something). Beside it is not a good idea to let an "app" (Activity, Service, whatever) run all the time. The Androidsystem will kick your process anytime to release CPU power and/or RAM. Bether use the AlarmManager to run your task when it is needed!

Comment: @blender- the main app should have  no contact with the second app.

Comment: You propably should explain this more clearly. Broadcasts are not bound to any app. You just hook your action into the ecosystem and get informed when it is fired. To change the lifecycle of a foreign application you must have root permissions and very deep understanding of the Android JVM

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating 2 app. You can write an service it will check every 20min in background and process accordingly.